# Was Boba Fett originally supposed to be in Episode 4?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

In the original theatrical release of *Star Wars*, Boba Fett does not appear. In the behind the scenes though, I recall Jabba was originally filmed (as a human, not a slug), and then the scene was cut.  The scene was restored in the Special Edition, with the human replaced with the slug.  Was Fett a part of that originally cut scene, or was he specifically added to the Special Edition?

Comment: considering he wasn't invented until after the original film and debuted officially in the Holiday Special....

Comment: @NKCampbell He's a recycled design of an early-draft version of Darth Vader (when Darth Vader was a rogue Bounty Hunter rather than a Dark Lord of the Sith), so he *was* invented before the original film, but was replaced by Darth Vader and then renamed.  He also debuted at the [San Anselmo Country Fair parade](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-real-first-appearance-of-boba-fett/) 2 months before the Holiday Special.

Comment: Yeah - that's true @Chronocidal - but did he have a name in the parade? :) Also - from a purely chronological perspective, the cartoon was in production prior to the parade: http://mentalfloss.com/article/72863/dark-side-oral-history-star-wars-holiday-special :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as you can see from the various versions of the film (below), Boba Fett was added digitally to the 1997 Special Edition.

As an added bonus, you can see the (almost) full original *original* scene here

Comment: Ugh. The bit where Fett mugs at the camera is truly painful to watch

Answer (score 4):

There is no mention of Boba Fett specifically in the shooting script, only "a half dozen grisly pirates and purple aliens":

```
  INT. DOCKING BAY 94 - DAY                                           

      Jabba the Hut and a half dozen grisly pirates and purple
      aliens stand in the middle of the docking bay.  Jabba is
      the grossest of the salivering hulks and his scarred face
      is a grim testimonial to his prowess as a vicious killer.
                               JABBA
                Come on out Solo!
      A voice from directly behind the pirates startles them and
      they turn around to see Han Solo and the giant Wookiee
      Chewbacca standing behind them with no weapons in sight.
                               HAN
                I've been waiting for you Jabba.
                               JABBA
                I expected you would be.
                               HAN
                I'm not the type to run.
                               JABBA
                (Fatherly-smooth)  Han, my boy, there are
                times when you disappoint me ... why
                haven't you paid me?  And why did you have
                to fry poor Greedo like that ... after all
                we've been through together.
                               HAN
                You sent Greedo to blast me.
                               JABBA
                (Mock surprise)  Han, why you're the best
                smuggler in the business.  You're too
                valuable to fry.  He was only relaying
                my concern at your delays.  He wasn't
                going to blast you.
                               HAN
                I think he thought he was.  Next time
                don't send one of those twerps.  If you've
                got something to say to me, come see me
                yourself.
                               JABBA
                Han, Han!  If only you hadn't had to dump
                that shipment of spice ... you understand
                I just can't make an exception.  Where
                would I be if every pilot who smuggled for
                me dumped their shipment at the first sign 
                of an Imperial starship?  It's not good 
                business.
                               HAN
                You know, even I get boarded sometimes,
                Jabba.  I had no choice, but I've got a
                charter now and I can pay you back, plus
                a little extra.  I just need some more time.
                               JABBA
                (To his men)  Put your blasters away.  Han,
                my boy, I'm only doing this because you're
                the best and I need you.  So, for an extra,
                say ... twenty percent I'll give you a
                little more time ... but this is it.  If
                you disappoint me again, I'll put a price
                on your head, so large you won't be able
                to go near a civilized system for the rest
                of your life.
                               HAN
                Jabba, I'll pay you because it's my pleasure.
```

So a character like Boba Fett is certainly a possibility for this scene, but the character does not seem to have been specifically planned at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

In the original comic book adaptation of the movie, this scene is included but without Boba Fett. Jabba the Hutt is depicted as a humanoid type, not a slug. At the time it came out, I wondered why this scene wasn't in the movie.

Comment: Do you have an image of this you can [edit] in to back up your answer? It looks like it could be a decent answer but evidence this is true would certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

No, Boba Fett was created after Episode IV: he debuted in the Star Wars Holiday Special, although he was first seen in a parade a couple of months before it to see how the crowds would react, and he ultimately ended up being one of the most hotly-anticipated toys for Episode V.

Comment: Whilst this answer seems to be correct can you [edit] in some evidence to back up your claims?